# Table in dataframe with vector of lists and vector

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I'm trying to create a plot of some data similar to the below example:

```
set.seed(1)
c <- rnorm(3)
df <- as.data.frame(c)
df$a <- strsplit(as.character(c), "1")
```

This gives the following:

```
> table(unlist(df$a))

-0.6264538     -0.8356286             0.           0047        0742332             24 83643324222082 
         1              1              1              1              1              1              1
```

What I need is to be able to create a 2D mapping, something similar to what I would have thought would have been created with `table(unlist(df$a), c)` however that command gives the error:

> Error in table(unlist(df$a), c) : all arguments must have the same length

The output should be something like (created by hand):

```
                            c
c                    -0.8356286   2410047 -0.6264538 0742332   0.  83643324222082
  -0.835628612410047          1         1          0       0    0      0
  -0.626453810742332          0         0          1       1    0      0
  0.183643324222082           0         0          0       0    1      1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `rep`eat the `df$c` by `length` of `df$a` and then use `table`

```
table(rep(df$c, lengths(df$a)), unlist(df$a))


#                   -0.6264538 -0.8356286 0. 0047 0742332 24 83643324222082
#-0.835628612410047          0          1  0    1       0  1              0
#-0.626453810742332          1          0  0    0       1  0              0
#0.183643324222082           0          0  1    0       0  0              1
```

where

```
lengths(df$a) #gives
#[1] 2 2 3
```

and then

```
rep(df$c, lengths(df$a)) #gives

#[1] -0.6264538 -0.6264538  0.1836433  0.1836433 -0.8356286 -0.8356286
#[7] -0.8356286
```